API access to ADM
Has anyone successfully been able to talk to the Sitecore ADM apis directly with something like postman? I am trying to feed ADM 100k specific contact ids, but the API only allows 200 contacts at a time.
I have tried to configure the Sitecore IM to give me a bearer token and use that token with the API, but still was denied access.

In order to fetch the bearer token for ADM request, you will first need to enable the non-interactive client login. This can be enabled through adding below configuration under the Config folder of the Sitecore Identity Server.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Settings>
  <Sitecore>
    <IdentityServer>
      <Clients>
        <!-- used to authenticate servers with client id and client secret -->
        <CliServerClient>
            <ClientId>{{ClientID}}</ClientId>
            <ClientName>{{ClientName}}</ClientName>
            <AccessTokenType>0</AccessTokenType>
            <AccessTokenLifetimeInSeconds>3600</AccessTokenLifetimeInSeconds>
            <IdentityTokenLifetimeInSeconds>3600</IdentityTokenLifetimeInSeconds>
            <RequireClientSecret>true</RequireClientSecret>
            <AllowOfflineAccess>false</AllowOfflineAccess>
            <AllowedGrantTypes>
                <!--
                    client_credentials authenticates with client ID and client secret
                    which is good for CI, tools, etc. However, it's not tied to a USER,
                    it's tied to a client ID.
                -->
                <AllowedGrantType1>client_credentials</AllowedGrantType1>
            </AllowedGrantTypes>
            <ClientSecrets>
                <ClientSecret1>{{ClientSecret}}</ClientSecret1>
            </ClientSecrets>
            <AllowedScopes>
                <!-- this is required even if not a 'user' for Sitecore to like us -->
                <AllowedScope1>sitecore.profile.api</AllowedScope1>
            </AllowedScopes>
        </CliServerClient>
      </Clients>
    </IdentityServer>
  </Sitecore>
</Settings>


Inside the above configuration, you will need to provide the values for ClientId, ClientName and ClientSecret1.
Thereafter on the Sitecore CM server, you will need to add the transformation for the above client id inside the identity provider. More details on enabling non-interactive client login can be found here.
Once the configuration setup is done, you can call below REST API to fetch bearer token.
POST URL: https://{{Sitecore_IdentityServerURL}}/connect/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Body:
grant_type: client_credentials
client_id: {{ClientID}}
client_secret: {{ClientSecret}}

Inside the above request, you will need to specify client id and client secret configured in the above file inside Sitecore Identity Server.
Above request will return you the bearer token. This bearer token then can be used to make call to ADM apis as below.
GET: https://{{Sitecore_CMURL}}/sitecore/adm/client/GetAvailableFacets
Authorization: Bearer {{BearerToken}}


Using above way, you will be able to access ADM apis using postman.
Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you face any issues.
